# how to pass dockerized program ip addresses of overlay networks attached to it

Tags: docker, networking, overlay

I have three overlay networks connected to container in a swarm and i need to give the addresses of the different networks to the program running inside when the container comes up.  Each network is for a different purpose and i cant seem to identify them within the container.

I've tried the usual IP a and `hostname -i` but it only displays the adapter information and nothing identifiable about which overlay is on which adapter.

```
lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth3@if118: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:00:0e:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet 10.0.14.3/24 brd 10.0.14.255 scope global eth3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth4@if120: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet 172.18.0.3/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth0@if122: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:ff:00:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.255.0.13/16 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth1@if124: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:00:0d:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet 10.0.13.3/24 brd 10.0.13.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth2@if126: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:00:0f:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet 10.0.15.3/24 brd 10.0.15.255 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
hostname -i
10.0.14.3 10.0.13.3 10.0.15.3
```

This shows the addresses but nothing identifiable about which is which overlay.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could write a script that runs on the host when the swarm service is started.  The script would run docker inspect on your container and write the network information to a file.  The file would be stored on a mount point that the container has mounted.  Then you can read the information from that file from within the container.
2. A more elaborate solution would be to build a custom API that would run the docker inspect for you and return the network information in a response.
3. Overlay networks are likely assigned to interfaces in order.  A little bit of testing shows this to be true, but I don't like relying on assumptions.

Comment: what we decided to do is assign the addresses to the loopback and sidestep the whole issue. thanks for the advice!